# Database Connectors in mule domain project

Tags: mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

We are building around 20+ mule projects and we are thinking if DB connector should be at domain level or individual project level. Please suggest. One drawback we can think of is that if one of the services is taking time or slow, it will impact other services as data base connection is shared.
Thanks,

Comment: Well, I always shared my config across all our apps with Domain project and didn't run into any issue so far.
I'm not saying this is the best approach, but imagine updating credentials or configuration across 20 apps vs. 1 domain project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share the connector libraries at the domain, or also the database configurations. A database configuration in a domain will be sharing connection with all applications that use it. If the connection is shared and one of the applications misbehaves then yes, it can affect the others by not releasing connections for example. On the other hand, deploying each app with the connector adds the library once per app, and you have to maintain all configurations separately. Shared connectors might make it easier to upgrade to a new version. Note that deploying a new version of a domain requires restarting all its applications.

It is up to you to determine if the trade offs are worth it or not. No one else can know the impact for your applications, the time to maintain, the effort to change configurations in 20 applications, etc.